# Have I read the data properly into the cshtml file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have created a code that displays a table with exchange rate data. Have I used loops and conditions (if else) in a good way?

```
@model IEnumerable<CurrencyResponse>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
@foreach (var obj in Model)
{
    <div>
        <h5>Table: @obj.Table</h5>
        <h5>Table number: @obj.No</h5>
        <h5>Date of publication: @obj.EffectiveDate</h5>
        @if (obj.Table == "C")
        {
            <h5>Quotation date: @obj.TradingDate</h5>
        }
    </div>
}
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Currency
        </th>
        <th>
            Code
        </th>
    @foreach (var obj in Model)
    {
        @if (obj.Table != "C")
        {
            <th>
                Mid
            </th>
        }
        else
        {
            <th>
                Bid
            </th>
            <th>
                Ask
            </th>
        }
    }
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var obj in Model)
        {
            foreach (var element in obj.Rates)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%">
                        @element.Currency
                    </td>
                    <td width="50%">
                        @element.Code
                    </td>
                    @if (obj.Table != "C")
                    {
                        <td width="50%">
                            @element.Mid
                        </td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td width="50%">
                            @element.Bid
                        </td>
                        <td width="50%">
                            @element.Ask
                        </td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, I'm using 4 loops to display the data the right way. I am using conditions to add extra html. I wonder if what I'm doing is right. Can it be somehow more optimized? In the created div I use h5 tags to display information about the table (A, B or C) and information about the date of publication of the exchange rates.

xml structure - (tables A, B, C):

[endpointA](https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A)

[endpointB](https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/B)

[endpointC](https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/C)

Comment: If this is working code than the question may be a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use two loops like this:

```
@foreach (var obj in Model)
{
    <div>
        <h5>Table: @obj.Table</h5>
        <h5>Table number: @obj.No</h5>
        <h5>Date of publication: @obj.EffectiveDate</h5>
        @if (obj.Table == "C")
        {
            <h5>Quotation date: @obj.TradingDate</h5>
        }
    </div>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Currency
        </th>
        <th>
            Code
        </th>

        @if (obj.Table != "C")
        {
            <th>
                Mid
            </th>
        }
        else
        {
            <th>
                Bid
            </th>
            <th>
                Ask
            </th>
        }
    
    </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>

            foreach (var element in obj.Rates)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%">
                        @element.Currency
                    </td>
                    <td width="50%">
                        @element.Code
                    </td>
                    @if (obj.Table != "C")
                    {
                        <td width="50%">
                            @element.Mid
                        </td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td width="50%">
                            @element.Bid
                        </td>
                        <td width="50%">
                            @element.Ask
                        </td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        
    </tbody>
</table>
}
```